# Angular md-datepicker define two differents dateformat

Tags: angularjs, datepicker

I have this angular.directive

```
    V1.App.directive('v1DatePicker', ['$compile', function ($compile) {
    return {
        restrict: "E",
        require: [
            'ngModel'
        ],
        isolated:true,
        scope: {
            id: '@',
            ngModel: '='
        },

        link: function(scope, element, attrs, requireds) {

        },
        template: '<md-datepicker id="id" ' +
        ' ng-model="internalValue" ' +
        ' md-placeholder="DD/MM/YYYY"></md-datepicker>'
    }
}]).directive('v1MonthPicker', ['$compile', function ($compile) {
    return {
        restrict: "E",
        require: [
            'ngModel'
        ],
        isolated:true,
        scope: {
            id: '@',
            ngModel: '='
        },

        link: function(scope, element, attrs, requireds) {

        },
        template: '<md-datepicker id="id" ' +
        ' ng-model="internalValue" ' +
        ' md-placeholder="MM/YYYY"></md-datepicker>'
    }
}]).config(['$mdDateLocaleProvider', function ($mdDateLocaleProvider) {
    $mdDateLocaleProvider.formatDate = function (date) {
        return date ? moment(date).format('DD/MM/YYYY') : '';
    };
    $mdDateLocaleProvider.parseDate = function (dateString) {
        var m = moment(dateString, 'DD/MM/YYYY', true);
        return m.isValid() ? m.toDate() : new Date(NaN);
    };
}]);
```

My point is: how can I define two different formatDate and parseDate? Both directive does the same, I just want that when I select a date from the first one, I see for example 23/03/2018 and from the second one 03/2018.
Is it possible or not?

Thank to everybody.

Comment: You should **not** tag your question as `angular` if it refers to the 1.x versions of Angular. Use `angularjs` instead

Comment: I don't understand, sorry... anyway this is Angular 1.6.6